# vi delete line with second occurence of pattern

Tags: vi, delete-row

I have a large file and many lines are duplicated. I'm trying to delete lines with every second occurrence of a pattern. Did tried searching similar question on SO but no luck.

I can delete all lines matching pattern with ":g/pattern/d" but don't want to loose data.

Sample pattern to delete "John-------Doe"

```
Sample data:  
Time--------FName---------LName

11:05-------John------------Doe   
11:05-------John------------Doe  
11:06-------Michael---------Lawrence  
11:06-------Michale---------Lawrence

Expected result:  
11:05-------John------------Doe   
11:06-------Michael---------Lawrence
```

Comment: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Uniq_-_Removing_duplicate_lines

Comment: I merely googled `vi delete duplicate lines`. The top two results were the link above and an SO question from 2008 with multiple answers.

Comment: @MillieSmith I will have a look, I searched "vi delete second occurrence of pattern" .. thanks and appreciate your reply.

Comment: Yes, it working, don't have any option to mark your answer as correct, but I have marked it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%!uniq` if file contains only sorted data

`%!sort -u` if file contains only data, but unsorted

`S,E!uniq` where S is starting line number of data, E is ending line number of data , assuming data is sorted

`S,E!sort -u` where S is starting line number of data, E is ending line number of data, for unsorted data